# Trouble using GSoap and SSL

Tags: soap, ssl, openssl, gsoap

I'm writing a gSoap client application against a service that has both standard http and https versions.  Everything I've written so far works fine with the http service, but when I switch over to the https service, suddenly I'm getting errors.

The only change I made to the code for https support was to add the following on startup:

```
 soap_ssl_init();   
 if(soap_ssl_client_context(&_tradeService, SOAP_SSL_SKIP_HOST_CHECK, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
     handleError("Failed to set up SSL connection");
     return;
 }
```

If I have the `-DDEBUG` flag on, I get an error about certificates: "SSL verify error or warning with certificate at depth 2: self signed certificate in certificate chain" which doesn't cause `soap_ssl_client_context` to return an error, and I don't think is a huge deal since while I'm testing I don't really care to authenticate the host.

The real issue is this error:

> SOAP 1.2 fault: SOAP-ENV:Sender [no
>   subcode] "Unable to handle request
>   without a valid action parameter.
>   Please supply a valid soap action."

which I get when I try and make a request to the service.  If I look in the send log that gsoap generates, I see the SoapAction parameter set in the outgoing header.  In fact, if I compare the send logs for the http/https services, the only differences is that the urls for the secure service are prefixed by https.

I then thought maybe something is messed up with the server, so I used curl to send the exact same XML data that gsoap logged it sent, with the exact same headers.  This works fine, I see a normal response with the data I expect.  This leads me to believe maybe I am setting up SSL incorrectly?

The other issue I had that was not in the docs, was that when I built with the `-DWITH_OPENSSL -lgsoapssl++ -lssl -lcrypto` flags I was still getting linker errors about gsoap's ssl methods.  I had to include `stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp` in my build in order to get these resolved, which I thought was odd.

Anybody tried doing this before that can give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we are fighting with similar problems at the same time.

Let me start with this first:

> The other issue I had that was not in the docs, was that when I built
>   with the -DWITH_OPENSSL -lgsoapssl++ -lssl -lcrypto flags I was still
>   getting linker errors about gsoap's ssl methods. I had to include
>   stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp in my build in order to get these resolved, which
>   I thought was odd.

FYI: I'm using VirtualBox, Ubuntu 14.04. I compiled Gsoap 2.8.21 from source with flags *--enable-debug* and *--with-openssl=/opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j*.

As you see, I also compiled openssl from source in order to get *libssl.a* and *libcrypto.a* archives. Additionally I compiled zlib in order to obtain *libz.a* archive. With all of them in place:

- I generated header file out of WSDL with command:

  ```
  wsdl2h -v -g -o temporary.h https://something.com?wsdl
  ```
- Added this line to temporary.h before generating proxy classes:

  ```
  #import "wsse.h"
  ```
- Generated C++ proxy client classes with command:

  ```
  soapcpp2 -1 -I/opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21/share/gsoap/import -C -j temporary.h
  ```
- With use of QT Creator (Plain Project, unfortunately no cmake), my project.pro file looked like:

  ```
  TEMPLATE = app
  CONFIG += console
  CONFIG -= app_bundle
  CONFIG -= qt

  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DWITH_OPENSSL
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DWITH_DOM
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG

  QMAKE_CFLAGS += -DWITH_OPENSSL
  QMAKE_CFLAGS += -DWITH_DOM
  QMAKE_CFLAGS += -DDEBUG

  SOURCES += main.cpp \
      soapBasicHttpBinding_USCOREIBarcodeWebServiceProxy.cpp \
      soapC.cpp \
      ../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21/share/gsoap/plugin/wsseapi.cpp \
      ../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21/share/gsoap/plugin/mecevp.c \
      ../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21/share/gsoap/plugin/smdevp.c \

  HEADERS += \
      BasicHttpBinding_USCOREIBarcodeWebService.nsmap \
      soapBasicHttpBinding_USCOREIBarcodeWebServiceProxy.h \
      soapStub.h \
      soapH.h

  include(deployment.pri)
  qtcAddDeployment()

  INCLUDEPATH += ../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21-debug/share/gsoap

  unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21-debug/lib/ -lgsoapssl++
  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21-debug/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21-debug/include    
  unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/gsoap/build/2.8.21-debug/lib/libgsoapssl++.a

  unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/lib/ -lssl
  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/include
  unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/lib/libssl.a

  unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/lib/ -lcrypto
  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/include
  unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/openssl/build/1.0.1j/lib/libcrypto.a

  unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/zlib/build/1.2.8/lib/ -lz
  INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/zlib/build/1.2.8/include
  DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/zlib/build/1.2.8/include
  unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../opt/libraries/zlib/build/1.2.8/lib/libz.a

  LIBS += -ldl
  ```

And answering your first part of question now, I think the following guides should fix the issues you are currently facing:

FYI: in main.cpp file I included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BasicHttpBinding_USCOREIBarcodeWebService.nsmap"
#include "soapBasicHttpBinding_USCOREIBarcodeWebServiceProxy.h"
#include "soapStub.h"
#include "soapH.h"
#include "plugin/wsseapi.h"
```

And later on in the file I added:

```
// creating empty soap struct with SOAP_IO_FLUSH
soap *soap = soap_new();
// setting flags: SOAP_SSL_REQUIRE_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION | SOAP_TLSv1
soap->ssl_flags = SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT;
// registering plugin
soap_register_plugin(soap, soap_wsse);
// file with CA certs of peers (downloaded https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/cacerts.pem.zip)
soap->cafile = "cacerts.pem";
// I placed cacerts.pem file in the same folder where your program executable will be created
```

So coming back to your case, I think in method you use *soap_ssl_client_context*, one of the params is also responsible for setting up the *cacerts.pem* location.

If this still does not work, you always can sett ssl_flags to *SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION*

I don't know if this can solve this problem:

> SOAP 1.2 fault: SOAP-ENV:Sender [no subcode] "Unable to handle request
>   without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action."

However there might be the case with attaching right file from gsoap plugins. I was playing with SOAP 1.1 and disabling generation of proxy client classes for SOAP 1.2.

Anyway, I'm looking forward to your response. Hope I could help u a bit and save a lot of frustration while dealing for the first time with Gsoap :)

Answer (score 0):

> If I have the -DDEBUG flag on, I get an error about certificates: "SSL verify error or warning with certificate at depth 2: self signed certificate in certificate chain" which doesn't cause soap_ssl_client_context to return an error, and I don't think is a huge deal since while I'm testing I don't really care to authenticate the host.

This error may not go away when you remove `-DDEBUG` for production use.  You can accept self-signed certificates by adding a verify callback:

```
soap->fsslverify = verify_callback;

int ssl_verify_callback(int ok, X509_STORE_CTX *store)
{
  if (!ok)
  {
    int err = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(store);
    switch (err)
    {
      case X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN:
        X509_STORE_CTX_set_error(store, X509_V_OK);
        ok = 1;
        break;
    }
  }
  return ok;
}
```

> SOAP 1.2 fault: SOAP-ENV:Sender [no subcode] "Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action."

The SOAP Action may be missing from the HTTP/S header or is incorrect for some reason.  This SOAP Action should be defined in the WSDL and is specific for each service operation invoked.

To set the SOAP Action parameter in the HTTP/S header, make sure to pass either NULL or a SOAP Action string as the third argument when making a call:

```
soap_call_SomeMethod(soap, "endpoint URL", "SOAP Action string", ...);
```

When you pass NULL, the SOAP Action string defined in the WSDL will be used.  Check the wsdl2h-generated code on what it says for the service operation to use as a SOAP Action.  The SOAP Action isn't really needed with gSOAP services, but other services e.g. WCF will throw errors at you.

When using a C++ proxy object, the call above is replaced by a simple method invocation:

```
proxy.SomeMethod("endpoint URL", "SOAP Action string", ...);
```

If you want to use the WSDL-defined endpoint and SOAP action then omit these parameters:

```
proxy.SomeMethod(...);
```

That's all.